# What would be the steps to create an sentiment analysis chatbot?

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

We have been assigned a project, in which we have to create a chatbot which will ask question, take the replies, analyse them and give an approximate assessment of the current emotional state of the person. There are two aspects of the project,

1. Training the bot to choose the next question based on the previous response
2. And analysing the responses individually, to detect . the sentiment.

What technology would we have to use and what would be the steps to accomplishing the tasks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some different approaches to learning this sequential acting. First, you can use RL (reinforcement learning) and define some rewards over the action of the user over that question, to explore and exploit the environment.

Second, you can use RNN to predict the preferred next question from a history of data. In contrast with RL, you need many instances to train the network to predict better next answer more accurately.